# Bash Script Cant Write To Log Files

Tags: bash, shell

I've created a simple bash script that grabs some data and then outputs it to a log file. When I run the script without sudo it fails to write to the logs and says they are write-protected. It then ask me if it should unwrite-protect them, but this fails (permission denied).

If I run the script as sudo it appears to work without issue. How can I set these log file to be available to the script?

```
cd /home/pi/scripts/powermonitor/
python /home/pi/powermonitor/plugpower.py > plug.log
echo -e "$(sed '1d' /home/pi/scripts/powermonitor/plug.log)\n" > plug.log
sed 's/^.\{139\}//' plug.log > plug1.log
rm plug.log
grep -o -E '[0-9]+' plug1.log > plug.log
rm plug1.log
sed -n '1p' plug.log > plug1.log
rm plug.log
perl -pe '
```

Comment: Are you familiar with all the principles in [this tutorial](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/understanding-linux-file-permissions/)?

Comment: Yes & I am stupid. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being dumb. I just needed to set the write permissions on the log files.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to write a file depends on the [file permissions](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/understanding-linux-file-permissions/) that have been assigned to that file or, if the file does not exist but you want to create a new file, then the permissions on the directory in which you want to write the file. If you use sudo, then you are temporarily becoming the root user, and the root user can read/write/execute any file at all without restriction.

If you run your script first using sudo and the script ends up creating a file, that file is probably going to be owned by the root user and will not be writable by your typical user. If you run your script without using sudo, then it's going to run under the username you used to connect to the machine and that user will need to have permission to write the log files.

You can change the ownership and permissions of directories and files by using the chown, chmod, chgrp commands. If you want to always run your script as sudo, then you don't have much to worry about. If you want to run these commands without sudo, that means you're running them as some other user and you will need to grant write permission to that user, whoever it is, in order to write the files/folders where the log files get written.

For instance, if I wanted to run the script as user **sneakyimp** and wanted the files written to /home/sneakyimp/logs/ then I'd need to make sure that directory was writable by sneakyimp:

```
sudo chown -R sneakyimp:sneakyimp /home/sneakyimp/logs
```

This command changes ownership of that directory and its contents to the user sneakyimp. You might also need to run some chmod commands to make sure they are writable by owner.